# How do I bootstrap C++ 2010 Redistributable with C++/CLI ClickOnce App?

Tags: c++-cli, clickonce, bootstrapper, prerequisites

I have an old C++ application that I have recently added CLR support to.  This was so that I could use mage.exe to generate the manifest files necessary to create the app as a ClickOnce app.  After some frustrating work, I was able to get the manifest files created.

Now, I want to create the setup.exe file similar to what you would get if you use the Publish option in a C# project.  The file would check for the Prerequisites of .NET Framework 4.0, Windows Installer 3.1, and Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable, and install if necessary.

I have tried using the Bootstrapper Manifest Generator but I am not sure how to get it to check for and install all 3 prerequisites and launch the ClickOnce .application file that I have.  Documentation for the product is a little piecemeal.

I have also tried unsuccessfully to use msbuild /target:publish to imitate the publish option you would see in a C# project.

I have even tried editing the .vcxproj file to include a BootstrapperFile (as demonstrated here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164294.aspx and [CustomAction succeeds on development computer, fails on deployment computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373890/customaction-succeeds-on-development-computer-fails-on-deployment-computer)) to no avail.

Is it possible to add some dependency in my application manifest (myapp.exe.manifest) similar to how the CLR is set as a preRequisite?

```
<dependency>
    <dependentAssembly dependencyType="preRequisite" allowDelayedBinding="true">
          <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Windows.CommonLanguageRuntime" version="4.0.30319.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
```

So, can anyone provide any guidance as to how I might generate an install package that checks for the prerequisites I mentioned above, install if necessary, then launch my ClickOnce .application file?  I think the difficult part here is that it is a C++ CLI Clickonce application and there is no IDE support to create the setup package.

Comment: Making CO apps from C++/CLI code was traditionally impossible due to the dependency on the CRT.  So you won't find a lot of help around about it.  You've got a shot at it again with VS2010, it no longer uses the CRT in the side-by-side cache.  You'll need to deploy at least msvcr100.dll as well.

Comment: Oh okay, that's at least promising.  I added a Setup & Deployment project just to see what it picked up as Detected Dependencies.  It showed Microsoft_VC100_CRT_x86.msm and Microsoft_VC100_MFC_x86.msm then packaged msvcp100.dll, mfc100u.dll, mfc100.dll, mfcm100.dll, mfcm100u.dll, and msvcr100.dll.  Do you think that it would it be a bad idea to include those as files copied to the client machine by ClickOnce (.deploy files)?

Comment: You *have* to deploy them, it won't run without them.

Comment: I do understand that I would have to deploy them.  I was just wondering if it is proper to install them to the same location as the exe as file dependencies of ClickOnce.  Update: I installed the dlls in the executable directory on a machine without the C++ Redistributable and voila it worked!  Just wondering, how does the exe know to find those dlls there and use them?  I suppose it checks the executable directory, then system directories if they aren't found there?